# command line to list the line number of the records that the length of field #4 not equal to 3

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

Is it possible to list line number of the records that the length of field#4 not equal to 3 in one command line?

Let say I have this data (Tab separator)

```
John Smith  25  O   ATG 180
Peter Jackson   40  AB  GGTA    173
Carl Anderson   32  A   GGT 172
Michael Phillips    28  B   TT  165
Lisa Mount  30  B   GTAA    168
```

Data in the field#4 here are ATG, GGTA, GGT, TT, GTAA.
So the output should be either

```
2
4
5
```

or (NULL can be replaced by anything)

```
NULL 
2
4
NULL
5
```

I prefer the first output. The second one is just in case that the first output is impossible to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{print $4}' input.txt | cat -n |
  grep -Ev '[[:space:]][CTAG][CTAG][CTAG]$' | 
  awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, but in Perl:

```
perl  -F'\t' -lane 'length($F[3])==3 or print $.' input.txt
```

Quick explanation:

- `-a` autosplits each line of the input
- `-F` (like in @holygeek's awk solution) allows to define the split pattern
- the result of the split can be accessed in the array `@F`
- `$.` is a variable which contains the current line number of the input